# Change Activity from menu

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, oncreate

First I am quite new to android. I am trying to get a simple map to change type, and though I could get mapType to act like a pointer, however it appears the because a value that onCreate uses changes doesn't cause the activity to refresh. Looking at examples on the web about menus they all seem to launch new activities, but I don't think launching a new activity and closing the old one sounds like best practice. So I am wondering how do you get an activity to pick up a change or can map be treated like a pointer and then could I refresh the map?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

 // Other supported types include: MAP_TYPE_NORMAL,
    // MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN, MAP_TYPE_HYBRID and MAP_TYPE_NONE
    map.setMapType(mapType);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int temp = item.getItemId();
    Log.v(Integer.toString(temp), "is");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.hybridSettings: 
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID;
        return true;
    case R.id.terrainSettings:
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN;
        return true;
    case R.id.normalSettings:
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code I see you don't call setMapType() in onOptionsItemSelected. The map cannot change without to call the proper method.

Comment: I can't access map from inside onOptionsItemSelected to call setMapType. As map is created in ocCreate

Comment: Set the map referenece as private attribute of your class or you can get the map fragment via FragmentManager.